# clojure:how to read data in chunk from a file

Tags: clojure

I want to read file out in chuck, and then insert them into database. Since if insert one record a time is slow, so I'd like to insert 1000 records a time, but how to do it using doseq?

```
 (with-open [rdr (io/reader file-name)]
   (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
      ;;how to split them in chuck lazily. so that not use too much memory.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(with-open [rdr (io/reader file-name)]
  (doseq [chunk (partition 1000 (line-seq rdr))]
    ;;Make an INSERT for all the lines in chunk
```

seems like it should work nicely.

Comment: Yes, `partition` is  also lazy. Well, when you use a new chunk it will eagerly realize all the values in that chunk with`doall`, but after that it'll wait lazily again.

Comment: When I use jvisualvm to monitor this approach it increases the heap size well beyond what just calling the function against `(line-seq rdr)` does. Since the comment in the original question says "so as to not use too much memory", is there more to answer?